# How to compare two text inputs line-by-line with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to compare if two text files are the same. The user will input them via two `<textarea>` elements on the page. Here's what I have:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['a'], $_POST['b'])){
    echo $_POST['a'] === $_POST['b'] ? 'EXACTLY the same' : 'NOT the same';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name='a' placeholder='File 1'></textarea>
    <textarea name='b' placeholder='File 2'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='GO!'>
</form>
```

This will tell me if the entire file is the same or not. What I want to do now is check which lines are different and return those. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't see files, i see text between `<textarea>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['a'], $_POST['b'])){
    $a = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['a']); $b = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['b']);
    $outl = ''; $outa = ''; $outb = '';
    foreach($a as $k => $v){
        if($v !== $b[$k]){
            $outl .= ($k + 1).'<br>';
            $outa .= $v.'<br>';
            $outb .= $b[$k].'<br>';
        }
    }
    echo '<table><tr><td>'.$outl.'</td><td>'.$outa.'</td><td>'.$outb.'</td></tr></table>';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name='a' placeholder='File 1'></textarea>
    <textarea name='b' placeholder='File 2'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='GO!'>
</form>
```

It explodes the inputs into arrays, each value a single line. Then compares them between a and b. If they're different, the line is added to the output. This is merely a very simple implementation and doesn't compensate for deleted lines; only those edited.